# version php en Debian Stretch

Tags: php, debian

Estoy usando toba y utiliza la versión 5 de php, pero el Debian 9 Stretch viene por defecto php 7. Si bien pude  instalar la versión 5.6, no sé como indicarle al apache que use la 5.6 y no la 7.

```
El problema es que las mayorías de las librerías que utiliza el siu,
requieren php 5 y no 7.
```

Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta actualizando las alternativas para PHP, con el comando:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Tambien deberias instalar el modulo **libapache2-mod-php5.6**, y luego hacer

```
a2enmod -m php5.6
```

Para más información puedes revisar la documentación oficial

https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg/update-alternatives.8.es.html
https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apache2/a2enmod.8.en.html

Comment: Eso configuraria el php de consola, no el de apache. Para el de apache, deberias instalar el modulo **libapache2-mod-php5.6**, y luego **a2enmod -m php5.6**